# What are the different software packaging formats and which distributions support them as part of base install?

Tags: linux, packaging

Which distros support RPMs?  Which distros support DEB packages?  What other distros and package formats exists?  Here is what I think I know, but am interested in getting a more precise answer:

- RPM - Redhat, Fedora, CentOS, SUSE
- DEB - Debian, Ubuntu,
- Pacman - Arch
- tar.gz - all, depends on what is in the compressed file though

Lots of others probably in the long tail.  I know you can use 'alien' to convert RPM to DEB, but it isn't installed by default in new Ubuntu setup so not counting that.

Comment: PKGBUILD is and tar.xz are the pkg formats for arch... off the top of my head you're also missing ebuild.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a list of Linux Package Formats on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_package_formats) and a list of common package management systems [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system#Common_package_management_systems_and_formats).